# ImportError: Incompatible Architecture for tokenizers.cpython-311-darwin.so in Python 3.11

Tags: x86-64, huggingface-transformers, arm64

I'm encountering an ImportError related to an incompatible architecture while trying to use the transformers library in Python 3.11. The specific error message is as follows:

> ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tokenizers/tokenizers.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tokenizers/tokenizers.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tokenizers/tokenizers.cpython-311-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tokenizers/tokenizers.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))

It seems that the issue is related to the tokenizers.cpython-311-darwin.so library being compiled for a different architecture (arm64) than what my Python interpreter is using (x86_64). Here are the details of my environment:

Python Version: 3.11
Operating System: M1 macOS Sonoma 14.1.1

I've already tried the following steps, but the issue persists:

- Updated transformers and tokenizers to their latest versions.
- Checked the compatibility of Python 3.11 with these libraries.
- Uninstalled and reinstalled the tokenizers library.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: how are you installing them?

Comment: just using pip3